# The argument type 'void Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(User?)?'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

How can I fix this error:
The argument type 'void Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(User?)?'.
[image]

```
instance.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
      if(user == null){
        //print('no user');
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
      }else {
        //print('there is a user');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

change the argument user to `(User? user)`

so the code would be:

```
instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if(user == null){
        //print('no user');
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
      }else {
        //print('there is a user');
      }
    });
```